# Convert SQL to LINQ Query

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have the following SQL query and I need to have it in LINQ, I tried several things but I can not get it working.

Here is the SQL query

```
SELECT     ST.Description, ST.STId, COUNT(SI.SIId) AS Expr1
FROM         BP INNER JOIN
                      MbrBP ON BP.BPId = MbrBP.BPId INNER JOIN
                      SI ON BP.BPId = SI.BPId RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      ST ON SI.STId = ST.STId
WHERE     (BP.CountryId = 1) AND (BP.RegionId = 1) AND (MbrBP.MemberId = 1)
      AND (SI.IsActive = 1)
GROUP BY ST.Description, ST.STId
UNION 
SELECT      ST.Description, ST.STId, COUNT(SI.STId) AS Expr1
FROM         SI RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      ST ON SI.STId = ST.STId
GROUP BY ST.Description, ST.STId
```

Comment: What you tried? And what was your problem(in convert)?

Comment: FYI it's **LINQ** - Language Integrated Query. Not *LinQ*. Been seeing a lot of that lately.

Comment: Sql is just better to use sometimes.

Comment: @Mardo IMHO, SQL is ALWAYS better to use for someone who knows SQL. just sayin.