# How can I convert this SQL to LINQ? (Inner Joins and subqueries involved)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
select * from EmployeeScheduleRoles esr 
inner join
(
    select esr.ScheduleID from Schedules sch 
    inner join EmployeeScheduleRoles esr on esr.ScheduleID = sch.ID 
    inner join Employees emp on emp.ID = esr.EmployeeID
    where emp.ID = 15921
) subqry on subqry.ScheduleID = esr.ScheduleID
```

Restriction: No 'Contains()' allowed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert SQL to LINQ Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988531/convert-sql-to-linq-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This LINQ query is equivalent of your SQL query (which appears not very optimized to me)

```
from esr in db.EmployeeScheduleRoles
join subqry in
  (from sch in db.Schedules
   join esr2 in db.EmployeeScheduleRoles on sch.ID equals esr2.ScheduleID
   join emp in db.Employees on esr2.EmployeeID equals emp.ID
   where emp.ID == 15921
   select esr2.ScheduleID)
on esr.ScheduleID equals subqry
select esr
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var yours = (from esr in EmployeeScheduleRoles
join sch in Schedules on esr.ScheduleID equals sch.ID 
join emp in Employees  on emp.ID equals esr.EmployeeID
where emp.ID == 15921
select esr).toList()
```

bt the way, your sql sub query is redundant, you can just    `select esr.* from Schedules sch`