# How do I convert this basic SQL statement to linq?

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

```
SELECT * FROM User
INNER JOIN Role ON User.User_ID = Role.User_User_ID
WHERE User.User_ID=’5’ OR Role.Role_Desc = ’admin’
```

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988531/convert-sql-to-linq-query]

Comment: Please show us your attempt, and also tag the language (e.g. C#)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL to LINQ Tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296972/sql-to-linq-tool)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
var result=
    (
        from u in db.Users
        join r in db.Roles
            on u.User_ID equals r.User_User_ID
        where u.User_ID==5 || r.Role_Desc == "admin"
        select new
        {
            User=u,
            Role=r
        }
    ).ToList();
```

Where `db` is the linq data context