# Sql to linq Convert with order by case condition

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, linq

Can any one help me in converting below `sql` to `Linq`? As I have tried many other ways without any success. Here is the code

```
select m.Menuname 
from tbl_RoleMapping r 
inner join tbl_menumaster m on Convert(varchar(100),r.Menucode)=Convert(varchar,m.Menucode)
where r.role='application support' and r.productcode='GL'
order by (case when (m.Menuname like '%BookingToolStripMenuItem%' or m.menucode 
                    like '%BookingToolStripMenuItem%')
               then 0 
               else 1 
               end) asc
```

here I wish search condition should come first then the rest.

Comment: Would be good to know your linq code

Comment: MySQL or MS SQL Server, which one are you using?

Comment: MS Sql server .......

Comment: Check this post in stackoverflow:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988531/convert-sql-to-linq-query

Answer (score -1):

Finally i got the desired answer by using Linq:

```
 DataTable dtquery = (from c in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                            orderby c.Field<string>("PMenu").ToLower().Contains(txtMenuName.Text.Trim().ToLower()) ,
                                                    c.Field<string>("Menu").ToLower().Contains(txtMenuName.Text.Trim().ToLower()) descending
                                            select c).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: This isn't related to the *question*. This code doesn't load the data using LINQ. The data was already loaded into a DataTable in some other way. The code doesn't make much sense either - `c.Field<string>("PMenu").ToLower().Contains(txtMenuName.Text.Trim().ToLower()) ` can only return `true` or `false`. Why not calculate that flag in the *SELECT* clause? Or used a computed DataTable column?