# How to convert this SQL query into LINQ in c#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

```
UPDATE  m
SET     m.Score = s.AScore + '-' + s.BScore
FROM    #Matches m
        INNER JOIN Scores s ON m.MatchId = s.MatchId 
        AND s.InfoTypeId = (
                             CASE 
                              WHEN m.SportId = 1 AND (m.StatusId >= 13 AND m.StatusId <= 17) THEN 10
                              WHEN m.SportId = 1 AND m.StatusId = 20 THEN 24
                              WHEN m.SportId = 1 AND m.StatusId = 21 THEN 23
                              WHEN m.SportId = 1 AND m.StatusId = 18 THEN 8
                              ELSE 5
                             END
                           )
```

I'm having two lists in C# one is Matches and 2nd is Scores, and I want to get the result from those list like the result this query will return. Means I want to update "Score" property of "Matches" list like it is being updated in SQL query.
Any Help Please.

---

```
Matches.ForEach(m => m.Score = (Scores.Where(ms => ms.MatchId == m.MatchId
                                                   && ms.ScoreInfoTypeId == ((m.SportId == 1 && m.StatusId >= 13 && m.StatusId <= 17) ? 10
                                                                              : (m.SportId == 1 && m.StatusId == 20) ? 24
                                                                              : (m.SportId == 1 && m.StatusId == 21) ? 23
                                                                              : (m.SportId == 1 && m.StatusId == 18) ? 8
                                                                              : 5)).Select(ms => ms.AScore + "-" + ms.BScore).FirstOrDefault()));
```

I have tried, but I think its too expensive. It is taking too much time. Is there any optimized way please.

Comment: Please refer to the following link.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988531/convert-sql-to-linq-query?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Which ORM do you use? EF 6, EF Core, LInq2db, something else?

Comment: It is unclear for me, what are you trying to achieve.1) You just want to generate exactly the same Sql somehow, 2) you want to make auto computed property 3) you want to design a solution, that makes the same, but in c# 4) something else?

Comment: With linq2db it Is easy. But EF query may depend on size of Matches - or just not possible.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, I'm working on .net Core. I'm not using EF. I have gotten the lists using Dapper. And I'm trying to achieve this concept using LINQ or lambda expression. Can you do this please. If you need more information about this query, just let me know, I'll provide it. Thanks.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, How can we achieve this thing using linq2db. Please can you help me regarding this query, or can you share any link which could help me. Thanks.

Comment: @ЯрославВиталиевич, you said right dear. can you do this?

Comment: There were several cases for chose, which one exactly do you need?

Comment: @PrinceKhanna, I have visited the link which you just shared. LinqPad supports minimum 3.0 .net core version and I'm working on .not core 2.2

Answer (score 1):

Try this example in LinqPad. You can use query syntax to join the 2 lists and iterate over the result to set match scores. I used a dictionary to simplify that switch case.

```
void Main()
{
    var matches = new[]{
    new Match{MatchId=1,SportId=1,StatusId=13,Score=""},
    new Match{MatchId=2,SportId=1,StatusId=18,Score=""},
    new Match{MatchId=3,SportId=2,StatusId=24,Score=""},
    };
    var scores = new[]{
     new{MatchId=1,AScore="10",BScore="0",InfoTypeId=10},
     new{MatchId=2,AScore="20",BScore="0",InfoTypeId=8},
     new{MatchId=3,AScore="30",BScore="0",InfoTypeId=5},
    };
    
    var dict = new Dictionary<int,int>{[13]=10,[14]=10,[15]=10,[16]=10,[17]=10,[20]=24,[21]=23,[18]=8};
    var data = (from m in matches 
               join s in scores on m.MatchId equals s.MatchId 
               where s.InfoTypeId == ((m.SportId == 1 && dict.ContainsKey(m.StatusId))? dict[m.StatusId] : 5)
               select new {m,s}
               ).ToList();
    data.ForEach(o => 
    { 
        o.m.Score = o.s.AScore + "-" + o.s.BScore;
    });
    matches.Dump();
}

class Match{public int MatchId; public int SportId; public int StatusId; public string Score;}
```

Comment: Hi Gokul, Thanks for the help. Let me try this solution. I hope that it will work. Thanks.

Comment: Cheers, mate! You can explore https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/ for learning LINQ. Also, LinqPad tool is a great playground to experiment and learn. They have a lot of LINQ samples from actual books that you can download and play with to learn. Good luck!