# How to do a SQL Query Proper way on LINQ and Lambda Expression LINQ C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

Hello How to i do a LINQ of a SQL Query Like this:

```sql
SELECT 
 c.Value as IPAddress,
 cd.Number as PrintNo,
 cd.TerminalNumber as TerminalNo
FROM 
 configuration c,
 ConfigurationDevice cd                    
WHERE 
 c.DeviceID=cd.ConfigurationDeviceID                  
AND Parameter = 'IPAddress'
AND DeviceID IN (   
    SELECT 
      ConfigurationDeviceID 
    FROM 
      ConfigurationDevice 
    WHERE 
     [Type]=1 
    AND TerminalNumber > 0              
)
```

Can anyone show a LINQ from Simple to a Lambda Expression of this Kind of SQL Query where another SQL Statement Declaration is done inside a SQL Query Statement.

Also this is what i've done so far but i also got an error on calling out the result column.

[image]

Comment: If you are using LINQ with SQL Database than you are using an Entity connection from your c# code to the database.  It looks like you are trying to use LINQ with a SQLConnection which will not work.   You could use a SQLAdapter and put query results in to a DataTable and then use Linq on the DataTable.

Comment: so you want us to translate your sql statement into a linq query ?=! the linq equivalent for the `IN` operator is the `Contains` method. and `AND` is `&&`. The select clause comes last. That should help

Comment: its the query inside another query i'm not familiar off with LinQ which is the critical part of my question that i want also to learn how.

Comment: there is no magic in nested queries. filter the second collection with where, make a select at the end and check with contains.: `firstCollection.Where( x => secondColelction.Where(...).Select(s => s.ConfigurationDeviceID).Contains(x.DeviceId)).Select(x => x).ToList()`

Comment: Possibly duplicate of [Convert SQL to LINQ Query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8988531/1260204)

Answer (score 1):

First, if you're going to write SQL, please write it as ANSI SQL and not Oracle SQL. ANSI SQL is more widely supported.

**ANSI SQL version**

```
SELECT 
 IPAddress as Value,
 cd.Number,
 cd.TerminalNumber
FROM 
-- also flipped the root as it seem to make more sense to me
 ConfigurationDevice  cd 
join configuration c on  cd.ConfigurationDeviceID=c.DeviceID
WHERE 
 Parameter = 'IPAddress'
AND DeviceID IN (   
    SELECT 
      ConfigurationDeviceID 
    FROM 
      ConfigurationDevice 
    WHERE 
     [Type]=1 
    AND TerminalNumber > 0              
)
```

You haven't shown anything about what you have entity-wise.

Entities

- Configuration
- ConfigurationDevice

```
var subQuery = (
  from cd in ctx.ConfigurationDevice 
  where 
     cd.Type ==1
  && cd.TerminalNumber > 0 
  select 
    cd.ConfigurationDeviceID 
);//.ToList();

var query = (
  from cd in ctx.ConfigurationDevice
  join c in ctx.Configuration on cd.ConfigurationDeviceID equals c.DeviceID
  where 
     c.Parameter == "IPAddress"
   && subQuery.Contains(c.DeviceID) 
  select new //Add a type here
  {
     Value = c.IPAddress,
     Number = cd.Number,
     TerminalNumber = cd.TerminalNumber
  });

var result = query.ToList();
```

Comment: "more wildly supported" brilliant! only for that you should get an upvote ;)

Comment: on the Subquery part it has an error that say :: CS1929: IQueryable<Guid> does not contain a definition of Contains and the best extension method overload 'MemoryExtensions.Contains<Guid?>(ReadOnlySpan<Guid?>Guid?) requires a receiver of type ReadOnlySpan<Guid?>

Comment: this may due to the ID im using its a GUID

Comment: @MikAA please add ur classes so we can see types and what you are attempting to do

Comment: @MikAA it would still be done the same way regardless of string, int or guid, so its something else but cant help if cant see

Comment: its setup on the table that its using a guid for primary and foreign key id

Comment: i love to do a screenshot and paste here but i cant upload a image of the code